# Understanding 1N5400 series datasheet

Tags: datasheet, bridge-rectifier

I am using 1N5408 diode in a rectifier circuit. The datasheet can be found [here](https://www.vishay.com/docs/88516/1n5400.pdf).

I find myself in a very bad state while understanding symbols and meanings while reading datasheets. Can anyone have a look and explain to me what the following terms signify, that is, what do you mean be them?

1. V<sub>RPM</sub>
2. I <sub>F(AV)</sub>
3. I<sub>FSM</sub>
4. V<sub>F</sub>
5. I<sub>RR</sub>

Also, can anyone confirm that the rectifiers can be used for converting 9V AC to 9V DC?

Comment: Those abbreviations are described in the "Parameter" column of the "Maximum Ratings" table in the datasheet.

Comment: OK, but I want to know the meaning of the terms too.

Comment: Running in circles here. That **is** the meaning of the term.

Comment: I want to know what each term means. For example, what does "Maximum Peak Repetitive Reverse Voltage" mean, and so on.

Comment: What part of it isn't clear?

Comment: It means the maximum voltage that can be applied repetitively in the reverse direction without damaging the part (because it's in the maximum ratings section).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VRPM - Max repetitive peak voltage. Can be applied repeatedly. This is often taken as the usual value of the maximum reverse voltage you'd expect the diode to be able to block, but as it's in the maximums section, it would be prudent to derate somewhat.

I F(AV) - The average forward current. This governs the heating of the diode. That's why they specify a lead length and a temperature.

IFSM - The short term surge. This is the sort of current you get into an uncharged capacitor when first switched on. It tends to be limited by the transformer impedance. It's very much larger than the average current, this is one robust diode.

VF - Forward voltage. We normally say 0.7v for silicon diodes, but this is specified for 3A so includes the effects of residual resistance.

IR - Reverse current, usually measured at maximum reverse voltage and maximum temperature, where leakage is worst. For some diodes, this can also be a significant source of diode heating.

Comment: This is what I wanted.

Comment: Tell me one thing: 1.2V forward current - that means I cannot use it for 9V rectification (even if the current is 5mA)?

Comment: That's 1.2V forward VOLTAGE, not current.  There will be about 1.2 volts across the diode when it is passing 3 Amps.  At 5 mA, the forward voltage would probably be around 0.6 volts, but you normally wouldn't choose to use a 3 Amp diode for such low currents.